# Which of these CSS rules renders faster?

Tags: css, performance

I am wondering which one out of the CSS rules below renders faster:

```
#avriable_info table td {width: 250px; font-size: 13px;}
```

or

```
#avriable_info table td {
    width: 250px; 
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any difference but the line-breaks. Where should a performance gain come from? 6 Bytes less to transfer to the client?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither one will be "faster" to render than the other because most parsers will normalize a file before parsing. e.g. Getting rid of white spaces and new lines and such.

Now, if you have a huge file that isn't being gzipped across the wire then the first one will *download* faster to the client than the second one which will allow the browser to start rendering it before the larger, slower one.

Answer (score 5):

Neither will make any noticeable difference.  A couple of newlines in your CSS is gong to make no more than a few CPU instructions difference to the rendering.

Maybe if you had a million lines of CSS you might notice a millisecond's difference, but if you're optimising that much (especially on a webpage!) you have far more serious issues to worry about (and they're not code related! ;-)).

Answer (score 3):

The difference is two line breaks. This difference is eliminated by the parsing of the file and is unnoticable compared to the parse time of the CSS.